# How to compile libraries with monotouch (getting error : attempting to JIT-compile with --aot-only)

Tags: .net, iphone, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use **DotNetZip** (http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) in a monotouch project.

I have re-compiled it for **monotouch**, by making two new monotouch projects under MonoDevelop (one for ZLib and the other for DotNetZip), putting the code inside, removing code that references Windows Forms, and setting **Compile Target** = **Library** in the project options.

I set the active configuration in MonoDevelop to "Release - iPhone" before compiling.

Then, I referenced the resulting DLLs in my main monotouch project.

That works fine when running in the simulator, but when I try to debug this on the actual device (an iPod Touch 4 in my case), I get an error at runtime:

**System.ExecutionEngineException has been thrown**

**Attempting to JIT compile method 'Vortaro.SearchTableViewSource:.ctor (Vortaro.SearchViewController)' while running with --aot-only.**

That happens on this line:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read ("dictionary.zip")) {
```

--

I also tested with a simple example that only does this when a button is clicked:

```
ZipFile.Read ("dictionary.zip");
```

and I get this error:

**Unhandled Exception: System.ExecutionEngineException: 
Attempting to JIT compile method 'Ionic.Zip.ZipContainer:.ctor (object)' while running with --aot-only.**

**at Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.ReadDirEntry (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zf) [0x000b5] in /Users/(...)/ZipDirEntry.cs:199**

When I look at the constructor to which the error points, I fail to see anything that could cause the JIT compilation:

```
public ZipContainer(Object o)
{
    _zf = (o as ZipFile);
    _zos = (o as ZipOutputStream);
    _zis = (o as ZipInputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation imposed by the iOS: it is not possible to generate code on deman.   So the issue that you need to igure out is why your code is trying to JIT compile the Vortaro.SearchTableViewSource.ctor, this could be done either because you had a generic type that uses it, or you are calling Type.GetType ()

The error does not look like it comes from the dotnetzip library, instead it looks like it comes from your code (See the type name)

Comment: I am not using reflection or generic types in my code. I tested again with a simple example that only does: ZipFile.Read ("dictionary.zip"); when a button is clicked, and I now get this error:

Unhandled Exception: System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'Ionic.Zip.ZipContainer:.ctor (object)' while running with --aot-only.

Comment: So it sounds like they are reflecting.   A simple fix (but will bloat your executable) is to disable the linker.

Comment: I have already disabled the linker. And I cannot see any use of reflection in the constructor referred to by the error message (see my question, I have updated it).

Is there a way to determine exactly what code is causing the "ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile" error?